# find consecutive transaction within 10 minutes

Tags: mysql

I have table like this

```
user_id order_id    create_time   payment_amount    product
101     10001      2018-04-02 5:26  48000           chair
102     10002      2018-04-02 7:44  25000           sofa
101     10003      2018-04-02 8:34  320000          ac
101     10004      2018-04-02 8:37  180000          water
103     10005      2018-04-02 9:32  21000           chair
102     10006      2018-04-02 9:33  200000          game console
103     10007      2018-04-02 9:36  11000           chair
107     10008      2018-04-02 11:05 10000           sofa
105     10009      2018-04-02 11:06 49000           ac
101     10010      2018-04-02 12:05 1200000         cc
105     10011      2018-04-02 12:12 98000           ac
103     10012      2018-04-02 13:11 85000           insurance
106     10013      2018-04-02 13:11 240000          cable tv
108     10014      2018-04-02 13:15 800000          financing
106     10015      2018-04-02 13:18 210000          phone
```

my goal is to find which user did transaction consecutively less than 10min.
I'm using mysql

Comment: has your create_time field datetime type?

Comment: yes @HamedGhasempour create_time column has datetime type

Comment: That's not a valid MySQL datetime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the format of your dates in the table, you will need to convert them using `STR_TO_DATE` to use them in a query. If your column *is* actually a `datetime` type, and that is just your display code outputting that format, just replace `STR_TO_DATE(xxx, '%m/%d/%Y %k:%i')` in this query with `xxx`.

The way to find orders within 10 minutes of each other is to self-join your table on `user_id`, `order_id` and the time on the second order being within the time of the first order and 10 minutes later:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.create_time AS order1_time, t2.create_time AS order2_time
FROM transactions t1
JOIN transactions t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                    AND t2.order_id != t1.order_id
                    AND STR_TO_DATE(t2.create_time, '%m/%d/%Y %k:%i') BETWEEN
                           STR_TO_DATE(t1.create_time, '%m/%d/%Y %k:%i') 
                       AND STR_TO_DATE(t1.create_time, '%m/%d/%Y %k:%i') + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

Output:

```
user_id     order1_time     order2_time
101         4/2/2018 8:34   4/2/2018 8:37
103         4/2/2018 9:32   4/2/2018 9:36
106         4/2/2018 13:11  4/2/2018 13:18
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4c0249c3698100cf01f6a02c55d58d8e)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```sql
SELECT user_id FROM `table_name` WHERE create_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(user_id) > 1
```